# I am working on topological search but giving me a error

Tags: python, data-structures, topological-sort

#Initializing the Graph Class

class Graph:

```
def __init__(self, numberofVertices):
    self.graph = defaultdict(list)
    self.numberofVertices = numberofVertices

def addEdge(self, vertex, edge):
    self.graph[vertex].append(edge)
```

#Implementing Topological Sort

def topogologicalSortUtil(self, v, visited, stack):
visited.append(v)

```
for i in self.graph[v]:
    if i not in visited:
        self.topogologicalSortUtil(i, visited, stack)
    
stack.insert(0, v)
```

def topologicalSort(self):
visited = []
stack = []

```
for k in list(self.graph):
    if k not in visited:
        self.topogologicalSortUtil(k, visited, stack)
    
print(stack)
```

tempGraph = Graph(8)

tempGraph.addEdge("A", "C")

tempGraph.addEdge("C", "E")

tempGraph.addEdge("E", "H")

tempGraph.addEdge("E", "F")

tempGraph.addEdge("F", "G")

tempGraph.addEdge("B", "D")

tempGraph.addEdge("B", "C")

tempGraph.addEdge("D", "F")

tempGraph.topologicalSort()  # SHOWING ERROR IN THIS LINE WHEN I RUN. CAN ANY ONE HELP?

Comment: could you please provide your error?

Answer (score 2):

unless "by showing an error" you mean syntactical error, there are no errors in the code.

I copied your code and removed all the errors related to syntax and indentation, the code is working fine. The errors are mentioned here.

- if you have not imported default dictionary from collections you should import using this line : `from collections import defaultdict`
- put visited = [] and stack = [] in separate lines.

These are the basic errors, but as you have not mentioned which error you are getting, this is the least one can do.